# mapKit в Андроиде. Определение геолокации

Tags: java, android, mapkit

Ребята, есть какая угодна, что нибудь по mapKit документация? У кого-нибудь, где-нибудь. Это какой то кошмар. Раньше с картами ниразу не работал, сегодня пришлось. Установил Yandex карты, все ок. Думаю: ничего себе, а Yandex то может, но как же я глубоко ошибался, когда наткнулся на "документацию". Именно в кавычках, потому что по другому ее никак не назовешь! НИЧЕГО нету, кроме пару описаний методов. И самое интересное, что в гугле - вообще ничего нет по Android+ API Yandex. Пару ссылок, которые описывают как добавлять Api в проэект. Все.
Необходимо реализовать определение геолокации пользователя по интернету. Если бы я на "ты" общался бы с гугл картами, быть может я и не задавал таких глупых вопросов, но к моему глубокому сожалению впервый раз сталкиваюсь с картами. 
Мб все же есть у кого нибуть мануал, док-тация ( даже от старых версий ) ,статьи, все что угодно, где можно получить инфу по данному api?
Понятие не имею, как написать определение геолокации пользователя. Мб кто может помочь? С меня просто огромный плюс и свечка за здравие в ближайщей церкве. Выручайте...

Answer (score 1):

Получать локацию вы будете используя Android-овский LocationManager.

Если вы хотите отобразить метку пользователя

`MapKitFactory.getInstance().createUserLocationLayer(yandexMap.mapWindow)`

где `yandexMap` это ваша View в макете.

Еще один нюанс который есть с картами, это `TapListener`-ы. В API Yandex-а они WeakReference и потому вам необходимо ручками их сохранять где-то в мест использования, а иначе они будут отваливаться постоянно.

Вот [тут](https://github.com/industradamus/YandexMapKitWrapper) я делал небольшую обертку для своего проекта. Можете посмотреть как и что там делается, может быть поможет.

Comment: Cпасибо,дружище,буду разбираться